# Séquence d'infinitifs

Tags: usage, infinitif

Le français me plaît bien, une raison étant les constructions avec des infinitifs successifs.

> Je pense pouvoir aller chercher les enfants.

Y a-t-il des cas avec plus de trois infinitifs successifs (y compris des prépositions au milieu) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il n'y a pas de limite en théorie. On peut facilement  trouver des séquences naturelles avec au moins six infinitifs :

> Il va pouvoir commencer à penser à aller se faire couper les cheveux.

Answer (score 2):

Oui, c'est certainement possible. Le nombre d'infinitifs pouvant se suivre n'est pas limité que par la loi de probabilité qui nous dit qu'il deviendra de plus en plus difficile d'en tirer un sens cohérent.

Pouvoir + aller a bien un sens ; aller + chercher est une unité idiomatique ; de sorte que « pouvoir aller chercher » n'a essentiellement que deux composants. Que dirais-tu par contre de cette série :

> Ah, mon lit ... Quand je serai soûl je vais y aller contempler pouvoir voler ramasser des beignes dans la lune.

Y en rajouter plus ne produirait, il faut se l'avouer, que des scénarios encore moins probables !

La situation s'améliore un peu lorsqu'on admet les prépositions. En effet, rien ne semble empêcher l'insertion de « essayer de » entre tous les paires ci-dessus si, bien sûr, ce n'est pas le style. Tandis que choix permet aussi de construire des phrases tout à fait normales comme celle de Stéphane. :)