# "Viens nous voir dimanche !"

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison, infinitif, impératif

For this sentence, since "viens" is in "tu" form, shouldn't it be "Viens nous vois dimanche !", since "vois" is the corresponding "tu" form? Like if it was in "vous" form, then it would be "Venez nous voyez dimanche !", so why not here?

Comment: See also https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30564/s%c3%a9quence-dinfinitifs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two verbs following one another *venir* and *voir*. Only the first one is conjugated, here *venir* in the imperative.  [The rule is](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/french-easy-learning/verbs-followed-by-an-infinitive) that the second one must be in the infinitive, you never conjugate it. This can be explained because it is a verb form used as a noun, it has no subject, therefore you cannot conjugate it.
So your sentences should be:

- *Viens nous voir dimanche*.
- *Venez nous voir dimanche*.

Be also aware of the sentence structure that is different from English. The direct object pronoun (here *nous*) goes between the two verbs and not after.

Other examples where the first verb is not in the imperative.

- *Nous allons manger*.
- *Je veux partir*.
- *Il est allé courir*.

Answer (score 3):

Voir (to see) is infinitive form. "Come (you) *to see* us on Sunday." In this sentence *come* is conjugated in the 2nd person singular but *voir* (see) is the infinitive form exactly like in the English sentence structure.

Comment: It isn't true that French infinitives and “to”+verb always match. In this particular case US speakers tend to say “come see us” while UK speakers are more prone to say “come and see us”. “Come to see us” also exists but it would be equivalent to “viens pour nous voir”. So I'm afraid your reasoning doesn't work here.